# jQuery slideToggle, show/hide speed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, show-hide

Is there anything in jQuery that allows you to specify the **speed** of a show/hide effect (as opposed to its duration).

Thanks.

Comment: there is a difference between the speed and the duration?

Comment: I suppose he might be referring to something approaching `duration = distance/speed`. It would probably require the offset to be calculated, then divided by a speed variable, etc etc...

Comment: @jAndy: ask the nice policeman next time you get caught speeding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build on Yi Jiangs comment, speed is a function of distance and duration, lets say you want it to expand at say `200px/s` to do that you need to use element height and basic calculus to figure out how long the animation should take, if your element is 300px high animation duration should be:

`300/200 = 1.5 seconds` or 1500ms, now apply that to http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ and we have a winner.

Comment: I was taking this approach and I'm not convinced it is giving properly consistent results. Maybe it's just an optical illusion though. I'll leave it like this for now.

Comment: `$(this).slideToggle($(this).height());`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
.hide("slow")
.hide("fast")
```

There is no real difference between speed and duration in this situation. If the duration is short, then it's fast (higher speed).

Answer (score 0):

Constant speed:

```
$element.slideToggle($element.height());
```